# Confused on how to interpret the energy eigenfunction of Hydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wavefunction, hydrogen, eigenvalue

So here is an image of the third lowest energy eigenfunction of an electron in a hydrogen atom:

[image: Hydrogen atomic orbital]

Image from https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTZEg.jpg

I understand well the eigenfunctions given by Schrodinger's equation for other types of potential energies, but the application to the atom is throwing me off, because of prior knowledge.

For an oscillating potential, or a constant potential, or some other variation, the qualities of the wavefunction make sense. The particle can be found anywhere inside the "box", and it is less likely to be found in areas of greater kinetic energy.

But isn't the pictured energy eigenfunction implying that there is a small chance for an electron with E_2 energy to be found in the first energy shell? I'm not sure how to interpret that. Isn't it also implying that the electron could be found *anywhere* between the wave functions maxima except for one discrete location where it equals zero?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. I'm pretty sure "first energy shell" means the ground state of the hydrogen atom, which is orthogonal to the state in the linked picture, so no: if the electron happens to be in the state you are showing, then there is no probability of being in the ground state. As for your last statement: yes, the electron can be found anywhere except for those discrete locations (of course, you can't measure a position precisely, so really there is some finite probability of finding the electron *near* those points).

Comment: What do you mean orthagonal? The eigenvectors are orthagonal?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the linked graph is a function of radius, no? 

Also, no I'm saying the opposite. I understand that the possible energies are only discrete locations, but the energy eigenfunction above seems to suggest otherwise, that there are discrete locations where it cannot be, but a small probability everywhere else.

Comment: Right, the eigenfunctions are orthogonal. Energy shells correspond to eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian for the hydrogen atom. The eigenfunction that you've shown is not the ground state, and so it must be orthogonal to the ground state. Hence, if the electron is in this state, there is no probability of the electron being in the ground state.

Comment: What could you possibly mean by "the possible energies are only discrete locations"? Do you mean that if the electron is in an energy shell, then it is at a discrete location? This is not true! Being in an energy shell means the electron is in one of the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, and yes: these functions are smeared out in space, so that if the electron has a well-defined energy, there is a probability of finding it at almost-all different radii.

Comment: Don't take the word "shell" literally.  It's not a shell like an egg shell.  Physics is always borrowing words from everyday life and giving them new meanings (*heat* and *work* are examples); otherwise we'd have to make up new words for every new concept.

Comment: @march I think you are thinking of it from an energy perspective, and I'm thinking strictly of the radial distance from the nucleus. The answer below clarifies a bit, though. You concur, saying that there is a probability of finding an electron of energy $E_n$ at almost all radii. 

But as far as I follow, it seems that the Bohr model was derived based on a geometric assumption - that an integer number of wavelengths of the wavefunction must fit in the "ring" of any given radial distance. This is why I thought that radius of an electron orbit was quantized, just like energy.

Comment: @jphollowed. Oh sure: Bohr used classical orbits to derive the Bohr energies and just stipulated that electrons would stay on those orbits and not radiate unless they jumped between them. But then, the Bohr model is *wrong*: it gets some stuff right but obviously not all, as you're discovering. The sense in which it's right is that it gets the *angular momentum* right: fitting an integer number of wavelengths in a circle around the nucleus exactly quantizes the angular momentum, yielding the correct $m$ quantum numbers, but that *doesn't* get the radial part right.

Comment: @march Even if his model is wrong, his logic seems like there is at least some truth to it. If the radial distance does change, then an integer number of wavelengths no longer "fit", and the wavefunction is nonsensical. So if there is a probability of the electron being at almost _any_ radius, then the deBroglie wavelength must be changing in order to "fit". is the problem here simply that we are using semiclassical orbits, and not using a local wavelength as in Schrodingers equation?

Comment: @jphollowed. I think the answer to your last question is a resounding *yes*.

Comment: @march so then why do we even talking about the Bohr radius, if particles are not actually constrained to a certain radius? Even in Schrodinger solution, is the particle still found in the general neighborhood of the Bohr radius? It has a nonzero probability to go to a lower radius, but that is simply synonymous with having a probability to drop an energy state? 

Basically I'm asking if radius and energy state actually have a correlation, or if it is a misleading artifact of the Bohr model.

Comment: @jphollowed. The Bohr radius is the *most probable* radial position of the electron in the ground state of the hydrogen atom. The wave function decays exponentially away from this position, and so we can say that the Bohr radius is roughly speaking the average size of the hydrogen atom. Energy and *average* radius are correlated (though not perfectly, I think, because the $l$ angular momentum quantum number matters, if I remember correctly). See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hydwf.html). Unfortunately, I can't continue this right now. Maybe I'll post an answer!

Comment: @march No problem, sorry for all the comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One has to keep in mind

1) that it is the complex conjugate square of the eigenfunction that gives the probability of finding the electron with energy E at a specific radius.

2) There are no fixed orbits in the quantum mechanical solution, only a locus of probability called **orbital**

3)orbitals overlap in space, it is the energy that is keeping the electron on a specific wavefunction.

What happens if you have an electron in [a higher energy level](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html#c2) ?  (please note that orbits are drawn for convenience, orbitals would make a messy graph) It has a probability of decaying to a lower one. It is only the electron in the ground state that stays grounded.

> But isn't the pictured energy eigenfunction implying that there is a small chance for an electron with E_2 energy to be found in the first energy shell?

Yes, it can overlap with  the orbital of a lower energy state.

> I'm not sure how to interpret that.

it is called probability of deexcitation, by emitting a photon.

> Isn't it also implying that the electron could be found anywhere between the wave functions maxima except for one discrete location where it equals zero?

Yes, it is how probabilities work. Have a look at [atomic orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In my physics class, it was never really stressed that discrete energy did not mean discrete radial distance from the nucleus. In fact, with the lack of clarification plus the way energy diagrams look, it seems purposefully implied that the radial distances were discrete as with energy. Thank you for the answer. So an electron of energy $E_2$ _can_ be found at the same radial location as an electron with energy $E_1$, at least monetarily, as this does not disagree with the Pauli Exclusion Principle? That only requires that their spin and energy differ, yea?

Comment: Though, you say that the orbital radii can overlap. Does this mean that the _probability_ functions can overlap, but if the electron with energy $E_2$ actually _physically_ ends up near the Bohr radius for $E_1$, it _will_ transition to the ground state? Or can an electron with energy $E_2$ end up near the Bohr radius for $E_1$ without transitioning? Basically I'm asking about the correlation between $E$ and $r$. Bohr makes it seem like they are basically synonymous. Schrodinger's equation solution for hydrogen seem to imply otherwise.

Comment: My essential question is this: Is the **probability of an electron of energy $E_2$ being _located_ near the Bohr radius $a_0$** in direct correlation with the **probability of an electron of energy $E_2$ transition to energy state $E_1$**? Seems that it is. Sorry for so many comments

Comment: The transition probability will have to be calculated using the wavefunction solutions. These depend both on delta(E) between the states and on the probability of overlap in space. The correlation comes through the wave functions and it is probabilistic. In order to transition there should be overlap in space of the two wave functions and also there should be the delta(E) that is required. A lower energy state does not have the energy to climb to a higher one even though the orbitals overlap.

Comment: Probabilistic means for example :out of a million overlaps in space 1 energy transition happens. This probability can be calculated using a quantum mechanical model with the wavefunctions of the states in transition.

Comment: "So an electron of energy E2 can be found at the same radial location as an electron with energy E1, at least monetarily, as this does not disagree with the Pauli Exclusion Principle" Now you have introduced a second electron, while we have been talking of a one electron sa in the hydrogen atom, at various energy levels. The Pauli exclusion comes when more than one electron is involved, and each can occupy one energy level labeled with its quantum numbers.